# DevOps template with conditional manual approval job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to add approval job based on the stage, I am using template and want to skip approval for some stages:

```
parameters:
- name: Stage
  type: string
- name: Environment
  type: string
- name: WebAppName
  type: string
- name: ArtifactName
  type: string
- name: DependsOn
  type: object
  default: [] 
- name: Subscription
  type: string
- name: isApproval
  type: boolean
  default: false 

stages:

############################################################
# Deploy stages
############################################################

- stage: ${{ parameters.Stage }}  
  displayName: '${{ parameters.Stage }} Stage'
  dependsOn: '${{ parameters.DependsOn }}' # this will execute based on the stage that is passed.

  jobs:
  - job: approval
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.isApproval }}', true)
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: ManualIntervention@8
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        emailRecipients: 'example@example.com'
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
            
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.Environment }} 
    ${{ if eq('${{ parameters.isApproval }}', true)}}:
      dependsOn: approval
    timeoutInMinutes: 70
    environment: '${{ parameters.Environment }} Environment'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: ${{ parameters.ArtifactName }}
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.Subscription }} 
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: ${{ parameters.WebAppName }}
              package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

And now from the release pipeline, I am passing values to the template:

```
- template: stages\deploy.yml 
    parameters:
      Environment: 'Dev'
      WebAppName: 'azureappservicehelloworldapp-dev'
      Stage: 'Dev'
      ArtifactName : '$(ArtifactName)'
      Subscription: 'AzureConnectionSC'
      # empty DependsOn, as Dev depends on nothing
      DependsOn:
      - Build

  - template: stages\deploy.yml 
    parameters:
      Environment: 'UAT'
      WebAppName: 'azureappservicehelloworld-uat'
      Stage: 'UAT'
      ArtifactName : '$(ArtifactName)'
      Subscription: 'AzureConnectionSC'
      DependsOn:
      - Dev
      isApproval: true

  - template: stages\deploy.yml 
    parameters:
      Environment: 'Prod'
      WebAppName: 'azureappservicehelloworld'
      Stage: 'Prod'
      ArtifactName : '$(ArtifactName)'
      Subscription: 'AzureConnectionSC'
      DependsOn:
      - UAT
      isApproval: true
```

If you see IsApproval is sent as true from UAT & Prod templates, so I should be able to validate approval for UAT & prod and DEV should be deploy without any approval.

But I am getting below error for the approval job in the template:

[image]

Manualintervention task is giving error, any suggestions plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ManualIntervention task has a `runOn: "server"` set on it, so you can't run it on an agent, it runs on the application tier.

This means you can't use:

```
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

[But you can set the pool to 'server' and use the 'ManualValidation' task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```
jobs:
- job: 
  pool: 'server'
  steps:
  - task: ManualValidation@0
    inputs:
      notifyUsers: 'me@example.org'
      instructions: 'check stuff'
```

The result is that it triggers a review. As expected.

[image]

For whatever reason, the ManualIntervention@8 task has an unsupported task execution handler in the context of YAML. So you can use ManualValidation@0, but not ManualIntervention@8.

Comment: Thank you, it worked on ManualIntervention@8 as well with no issues, what is not supported with ManualIntervention@8 ?

Comment: I take it back, i am getting error: Error analysis
ManualIntervention (ManualIntervention)

Task execution section of task definition for ID: bcb64569-d51a-4af0-9c01-ea5d05b3b622 is either missing or not valid.

Comment: Yeah, `ManualIntervention` uses `"execution": {"RM:ManualIntervention": {}}`, which isn't supported by the YAML pipeline expansion. The `ManualValidation` task doesn't use the `RM:` namespace for the execution handler.

Comment: The error message and the fact that the task shows up in the YAML editor is super confusing.

Comment: I'm guessing that Microsoft deprecated this task for YAML at some point. The doc says it's not supported, but it clearly works under some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

the `Manual Intervention` task is only available for Classic releases, and there only for an agentless job phase of a release.

In your case, what I would do is to inject two new placeholder environments into the pipeline, each of which has an approval requirement, but which deploys nothing:

```yaml
  - template: stages\deploy.yml 
    parameters:
      Environment: 'Dev'
      WebAppName: 'azureappservicehelloworldapp-dev'
      Stage: 'Dev'
      ArtifactName : '$(ArtifactName)'
      Subscription: 'AzureConnectionSC'
      # empty DependsOn, as Dev depends on nothing
      DependsOn:
      - Build

  - stage: UATApproval  
    displayName: 'UAT Approval Stage'
    dependsOn: 'Dev'
    jobs:
    - deployment: UATApproval
      environment: 'UAT Approval Environment'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - pwsh: Write-Host "Placeholder approval deployment."

  - template: stages\deploy.yml 
    parameters:
      Environment: 'UAT'
      WebAppName: 'azureappservicehelloworld-uat'
      Stage: 'UAT'
      ArtifactName : '$(ArtifactName)'
      Subscription: 'AzureConnectionSC'
      DependsOn:
      - UATApproval
      isApproval: true

  - stage: PRODApproval  
    displayName: 'PROD Approval Stage'
    dependsOn: 'UAT'
    jobs:
    - deployment: PRODApproval
      environment: 'PROD Approval Environment'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - pwsh: Write-Host "Placeholder approval deployment."

  - template: stages\deploy.yml 
    parameters:
      Environment: 'Prod'
      WebAppName: 'azureappservicehelloworld'
      Stage: 'Prod'
      ArtifactName : '$(ArtifactName)'
      Subscription: 'AzureConnectionSC'
      DependsOn:
      - PRODApproval
      isApproval: true
```

If you like, you could "templatize" those stages as you did your other deployment stages.

Comment: in UATApproval or ProdApproval stages how to include ManualIntervention, I only see pwsh: Write-Host "Placeholder approval deployment." how does this step do the manual intervention ?

Comment: What this does is run a trivial job (write some output). And then stop. You then put an approval condition on the environment itself in Azure Pipelines. Once the job runs, the next won't run until someone approves the trivial work you just "deployed".