# YAML - Execute template in Deploymentjob

Tags: azure, yaml

I'm currently trying to setup my complete build/release pipeline with yaml files.
First I tried with different stages (dev/staging/prod) and it worked.
Now I wanted to add an approval that the deploy doesn't not happen automatically on each system.

Therefore I added an environment in the TFS with an approval check.
But when I try to setup the yaml file I always get an error.
I don't know how to setup this properly.

This is my main yaml file called release-pipeline.yaml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: POOL

stages:
- stage: BuildSolution
  jobs:
    - job: BuildSolutionJob
      displayName: Build
      workspace:
        clean: all
      steps:
        - template: yaml/BuildSolution.yml
        - template: yaml/CopyFiles.yml
        - template: yaml/PublishArtifact.yml
 
- stage: DeployOn_STAGING_System
  dependsOn: BuildSolution
  jobs:
    - job: Deploy_STAGING
    - template: yaml/Deploy.yml
      parameters:
        Environment: 'SITE'
        Staging: 1
- stage: Deploy_DEV_System
  dependsOn: BuildSolution
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy_DEV
      environment: ENVCHECK_DEV
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - template: yaml/Deploy.yml
            parameters:
              Environment: 'SITE'
              ViewDeploy: 1
```

This is my Deploy.yml file which i want to execute (only some snips):

```
parameters:
    - name: Environment
      type: string
    - name: ProdSystem
      type: number
      default: 0
    - name: Staging
      type: number
      default: 0
    - name: ViewDeploy
      type: number
      default: 0
    
jobs:
  - job:
    variables:
      artifactName: $[stageDependencies.BuildSolution.BuildSolutionJob.outputs['SetVariables.artifactName']]
      version: $[stageDependencies.BuildSolution.BuildSolutionJob.outputs['SetVariables.version']]
    steps:   
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Display given parameters
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: >
          
            Write-Host "ArtifaceName: " $(artifactName)
            
            Write-Host "Environment for Deploy: " ${{ parameters.Environment }}
       
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isStaging]${{ parameters.Staging }}"
          failOnStderr: true
```

When I try to execute I get the following error:
/release-pipeline.yml: Unexpected value 'parameters'.

How do I need to change this that it will work with the template in both cases, with and without the environment approval check?

I tried https://samlearnsazure.blog/2020/02/05/approvals-in-environments/
and of course different structure for the calling. But nothing helped.
In the tutorials they always have steps below the "deploy" but because I have different sites and environments I want/need the template file to save work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please *tag* your question properly – [tag:yaml] alone is too generic and people knowledgable about your problem will probably not see this question. You seem to be using Azure so that would be a relevant tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another post which goes in the same direction.

I reworked my complete template so that I can use the approach of this: [DevOps template with conditional manual approval job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338737/devops-template-with-conditional-manual-approval-job)
It's not the same as I wanted, but it works.
My goal was that I don't want to create a environment if I have no checks on this site. Only for sites where I wanted the approval check.
With the above mentioned solution I need to create an environment for each site, independent if I have checks or not.